# How to login in a website While web scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube

I am making a web scraper that can bring back my YouTube channel stats in python , so I went to my YT studio site and copied the link and pasted it print the soup using bs4.I took the whole test that was printed and created an html file and when i looked at it , it was the YouTube login page.

So now i want to login into this(lets say i can provide the password and email id in a text file) in order to scrape the yt studio stats.**I have no idea bout this** (im new to web scraping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [youTubeAPI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) to perform your operation. If you are still looking for a method to perform via web scraping below is the code for it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver= webdriver.Chrome('')
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com');

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click();

driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
```

While doing via web scraping after entering an email address and trying to enter the password field, you may come across an error like below. It will happen because of multiple reasons like two-factor auth, not the secure browser.

you can disable two-factor auth for your login and give it a try with web scraping it will help

[image: Error Image because of two factor auth]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3), you don't need web scraping for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You likely login via a POST request. So you'll want to use a browser and login to YouTube while monitoring the Network using the browser. If you're using Firefox, it would be [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), if you're using another browser it should have an equivalent. You'll want to find the form request it sends and then replicate that.

Although, if you're that new to web scraping, you might be better off starting with something easier or using YouTube's API.